# Getting and using Bearer with sequence in Message Mediation Policies

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I use message mediation policies in which is the sequence that provides bearer that I pass to the end point configured in the API. However I get response 202 undocumented. Do you know where could be the problem?

According to logs it seems that the flow is not going through gateway, the end point defined in implement is not called.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="GetBearer" trace="disable" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="msg" value="*****INITIATING*****"/>
    </log>
    <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
        <format>
            <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
                <soapenv:Body>
                    <root>
                        <grant_type>client_credentials</grant_type>
                        <client_id>{{client_id}}</client_id>
                        <client_secret>{{client_secret}}</client_secret>
                        <resource>{{resource}}</resource>
                    </root>
                </soapenv:Body>
            </soapenv:Envelope>
        </format>
        <args/>
    </payloadFactory>
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="msg" value="*****BEFORE TOKEN SERVICE CALL*****"/>
        <property expression="get-property('axis2','REST_URL_POSTFIX')" name="URLSave"/>
    </log>
    <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
    <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
    <property name="Content-Type" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
    <property name="Accept" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
    <property name="DISABLE_CHUNKING" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="true"/>
    <property name="HTTP_METHOD" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="POST"/>
    <property action="remove" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2"/>
    <log level="full"/>
    <call blocking="true" description="Getting bearer">
        <endpoint>
            <http format="rest" method="post" uri-template="{{URI_of_website}}"/>
        </endpoint>
    </call>
    <log level="custom">
        <property name="msg" value="*****AFTER TOKEN SERVICE CALL*****"/>
    </log>
    <property expression="get-property('axis2','URLSave')" name="REST_URL_POSTFIX" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
    <property expression="json-eval($.access_token)" name="bearer" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
    <property expression="fn:concat('Bearer ', get-property('bearer'))" name="Authorization" scope="transport" type="STRING" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    <log level="custom">
        <property expression="get-property('access_token')" name="Bearer"/>
        <property expression="get-property('bearer')" name="Bearer2"/>
        <property expression="get-property('axis2','REST_URL_POSTFIX')" name="URLSaveLog"/>
    </log>
    <header expression="fn:concat('Bearer ', get-property('bearer'))" name="Authorization" scope="transport"/>
</sequence>
```

I expect to receive json with data.

### ## Wire Logs ##

TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:53,975] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "GET /t/dev.nug.no/temp/v1/api/area/ HTTP/1.1[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:53,975] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Host: tstl-apimgmt.nug.no[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:53,975] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:53,975] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "accept: application/json[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:53,975] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Authorization: Bearer 9d486535-8f61-32da-8ddc-2572t5fe73a7[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:53,975] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.100 Safari/537.36[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:53,975] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Referer: https://tstl-apimgmt.nug.no/store/apis/info?name=WatertempAPI&version=v1&provider=NUG%2Fadmin%40dev.nug.no&tenant=dev.nug.no[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:53,975] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:53,976] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,cs;q=0.8,sk;q=0.7[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:53,976] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "Cookie: i18next=en-US; region1_configure_menu=none; region4_monitor_menu=none; region5_tools_menu=none; menuPanel=visible; region3_registry_menu=visible; menuPanelType=main; requestedURI=../../carbon/tenant-dashboard/index.jsp; current-breadcrumb=identity_menu%252Cuserstores_mgt_menu%252Cuserstores_mgt_menu_list%2523; fpc=AjtoARc_6bZHl2PfzBFkD1hw; stsservicecookie=ests; x-ms-gateway-slice=prod; JSESSIONID=BF282Z76CF90CE17D59F8685DX1E8485; csrftoken=9pttdibi9fmeek4ur9bu9tpb66[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:53,976] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "X-Forwarded-For: 192.168.16.113[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:53,976] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 >> "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [3] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:54,055] @dev.nug.no [3] [AM] INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  msg = *****INITIATING***** {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [3] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:54,067] @dev.nug.no [3] [AM] INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  msg = *****BEFORE TOKEN SERVICE CALL*****, URLSave = /api/area/ {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [3] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:54,068] @dev.nug.no [3] [AM] INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  To: local://axis2services/temp/v1/api/area/, MessageID: urn:uuid:85d4f453-0094-459e-b4af-ec748c097424, Direction: request, Envelope: client_credentials{{client_id}}{{client_secret}}{{resource}} {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [3] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:54,439] @dev.nug.no [3] [AM] INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  msg = *****AFTER TOKEN SERVICE CALL***** {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [3] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:54,453] @dev.nug.no [3] [AM] INFO {org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator} -  Bearer = null, URLSaveLog = /api/area/
{org.apache.synapse.mediators.builtin.LogMediator}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:54,464] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "HTTP/1.1 202 Accepted[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:54,466] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Date: Tue, 25 Jun 2019 07:08:54 GMT[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:54,466] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Transfer-Encoding: chunked[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:54,466] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "Connection: keep-alive[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:54,466] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:54,466] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "0[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}
TID: [-1] [] [2019-06-25 10:08:54,466] DEBUG {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire} -  HTTPS-Listener I/O dispatcher-2 << "[\r][\n]" {org.apache.synapse.transport.http.wire}

Comment: Could you provide us the wire logs of the gateway? Could you observe the token service call happens?

Comment: @Menaka I uploaded the wire logs to the description.